# Using variable in a regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i have the following variables:

```
myId; //Email_PDF
currentHoverOnItem; //Email_PDF_english of Email_PDF_Dutch or ...
```

So the first value is "Email_PDF" and the second is "Email_PDF_english". What i want i when currentHoverOnItem contains myId, then something can be executed.
This is what i have so far:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^/"+myId+"/$");

if (currentHoverOnItem.match(pattern))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Is this the right way to use the regex? It should match part of the string, there can be text before or after the match.

Comment: Providing that currentHoverOnItem returns a string then there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. Except the $ in the pattern means that you won't get a match with values you have given in the example.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var pattern = new RegExp(myId, "g");

if (currentHoverOnItem.match(pattern))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right way to use the regex?

No! Regexes are for patterns, not for literal strings. Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if (currentHoverOnItem.indexOf(myId) >= 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is "anchored", meaning that ^ and $ specifiy begin and end of your string.
To match "Email_PDF_english" in an anchored pattern you could use
^Email_PDF_(.*)$, but it won't match if your string is longer, as your comment suggests.

If it's not anchored you could test for a blank following the Email_PDF_... string, ie
Email_PDF_([^\s]*)\s+

Answer (score 0):

You need not use a reg_exp here. Using indexOf will do the trick for you

```
if(currentHoverOnItem.indexOf(myId) != -1)
{
    //Do something
}
```